# How can I concatenate two strings into one using LLBLGen Pro

Tags: linq, llblgenpro

As the error says, I think `LLBLGen`  have their own custom functions but official documentation doesn't help much. Is there any way to concatenate these two strings and make into one while LINQ querying?

```
   var viewModelCarrierDivisionQuery = from division in database.CarrierDivision
                                                    where division.CarrierId == carrierId
                                                    join carrier in database.Carrier
                                                    on division.CarrierId equals carrier.CarrierId
                                                    select new CarrierDetailViewModel.DivisionModel {
                                                        Id = division.CarrierDivisionId, 
                                                        Name = string.Join(" / ", carrier.Name, division.DivisionName)
                                                    };
```

```
SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.ORMQueryConstructionException: 'Method call to 'Join' doesn't have a known mapped database function or other known handler.'
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have used is just a simple solution with plus `name +" / "+name`. This works. Is there any better way out there?